Tailwind not working with Visual Studio 2022 Angular project
I have a .NET Core & Angular project in VS. I’m trying to use Tailwind.
If I run ng serve in the terminal, my Tailwind styles show up correctly. However, if I click “Start” in VS, the Tailwind styles do not show at all. Does anyone know why these would behave differently?
I have tried

changing the frontend project’s StartupCommand to ng serve and npm start
adding a postcss.config.js file
putting tailwindcss and postcss into the package.json dependencies


Sorry to disturb. Did you ever manage to resolve this? I have the same issue

I really don't understand, but I resolved this by simply rebooting my PC!?!
